# Sending multiple transactions as once

Tags: python, solidity, web3py, ganache

What are some ways to send multiple transactions at once to a ganache blockchain ?

I am using the web3.py library.

Answer (score 2):

Ethereum does not support sending multiple transactions once.

Only way to do any kind of multi-transaction logic is to write your own smart contract.

Alternatively you can use another blockchain, like Cosmos SDK based ones, which support sending multiple transactions once.